# How to generate absolute directory while exporting HTML

Tags: export, html

```
ExportString["Test","HTML"]
Export["Test.html","test","HTML"]

 <link href="HTMLFiles/m-478f1adf-0b36-429c-9ee2-ff6f5c953e52.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

the Directory is HTMLFiles
How to make it be the absolute directory, For instance

```
Directory[]<>"\\HTMLFiles"
```

I done it by `StringReplace` before. Is there any setting in Mathematica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by HTMLFragment which introduced in 2014.

```
ExportString[
BarChart[{1}], 
"HTMLFragment", 
"URIHandler" -> "Export", 
"FilesPrefix" -> "http://localhost/media/temp"]

output:
<img src=\"http:/localhost/media/temp/kqh0jxxfrg57.jpg\" \
class=\"img-responsive\"/>
```